# Java String Formatter

Tags: java

I'm wondering if there is a String formatter in java similar to the java DecimalFormat("0.#")

I have the following set of numbers that needs to be masked with dashes, "00-0000-00", I was hoping there would be a formatter that would enable me to do this in a similar way you handle DecimalFormat("00-0000-00"). If such a method doesn't exist, could someone please provide an example of an alternate solution.

I need to strip the dashes when saving to the database and add them back in when retrieving them from the database.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the Java Formatter object?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Comment: The only thing I can think of is modulo `%` the number and plug in the formatter string. As for revert it back, `replaceAll("-", "")` and `parseInt` are the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you looked at `String.format("%2d-%4d-%2d", int1, int2, int3)`?

Example:

```
    int n = 12345678;
    String formatted = String.format("%2d-%4d-%2d", n / 1000000, (n / 100) % 10000, n % 100);
    int orig = Integer.valueOf(formatted.replace("-", ""));
    System.out.println(String.format("formatted=%s, orig=%d", formatted, orig));
    // formatted=12-3456-78, orig=12345678
```

Comment: +1 exactly what I was thinking about posting,but you beat me to it.

Comment: @phatfingers Thanks, I figured this was probably going to be my only option, was just hoping java had something much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Java does have a [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method.

Then use [replace all](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for converting back.

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom method and its reverse. The former will be called before adding to your db and the latter after retrieving your db. Shouldn't be much of problem, I believe.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I planned to do, I was just hoping for a simple formatter, but it's looking like String.format is my simplest option.